# Convert VB Code Loop into Java Loop

Tags: java, vb.net, loops

```
    Public Function epwd(pwd As String) As String
    pwd = UCase(pwd)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To Len(pwd)
        epwd = epwd + Chr(Asc(Mid(pwd, i, 1)) + 7)
    Next
    End Function
```

I want to convert this loop into JAVA loop ...

Comment: i tried this .. and not getting right result
public static String epwd(String pwd) {
        pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
        String epwd = "";
        int i;
        for (i = 1; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
            epwd = epwd + ((char) (pwd.charAt(i) + 7));
        }
        return epwd;
    }

Comment: @AboZyaD please [edit] you question with that information. Code doesn't fit into comments quite so well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
public String epwd(String pwd) {
  pwd = pwd.toUpperCase();
  String epwd = "";
  int i;
  for (i=0; i < pwd.length(); i++) {
    epwd = epwd + ((char)(pwd.charAt(i) + 7));
  }
  return epwd;
}
```

Comment: I test this code .. and it is seame as i tried ..when i enter letter(i) return empty ..

Comment: Can you add in the question an example of input and expected output?

Comment: The ending condition in VB is inclusive, so you need to change this to: i <= pwd.length();

Comment: @DaveDoknjas Indices in Java start from zero. Because it I changed `i=0`.

Comment: @djm: Yes, either way handles that - changing the index boundaries or adjusting for the 1-based indexing within the loop body.